# objectAtIndex is giving an ascii value

Tags: ios, objective-c

im new to iOS, the following code gave me an ascii value:

```
 NSArray *arry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@'a',@'b',@'c', nil];
 NSString *x = [arry objectAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"%@", x);
```

output: 97

But i need it to print:  a   , not ascii, here is what i tried:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", x];
```

but that didnt work

Comment: use [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that simple quote maps to a char not a NSString. This should work :

```
NSArray *arry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

A really nice trick :)

The thing that is going on is that c `char` types are written in `'` and they're basically ASCII values. On other hand ObjC has a thing called [literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) and one of them allows for conversion from a number to a `NSNumber` type.

What happens here is that your characters get converted into an ASCII equivalent (to an integer actually just a one byte integer - `char`) and then into `NSNumber`s. `'a'` in ASCII is `97`. So:
`'a' -> ASCII 97 -> Wrapped in a NSNumber`

You want your array to contain strings so you want to do:

`NSArray *arry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];`

`NSArray` can only contain objects (and `NSNumber` is an object) that's why you'll have to use `NSString`s. If you want chars in your array you'll have to use c style arrays.

Comment: Good answer. Info about conversion to `NSNumber` is crucial to explain the results the OP was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

String literals in Objective-C must be wrapped in double quotes

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
NSString *x = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", x);
```